# How to sum multiple different objects in an array using Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting started with Vue. I am struggling to calculate the sum of different elements in an object of an array.

My array looks like this:

```
    sites: [{
       sku: 10001,
       name: "Product A",
       totalPrice: '',
       values: [{
          price: 10,
          discount: 5,
          color: "red"
       },
       {
           price: 15,
           discount: 8,
           color: "black"
       }]
    },
    {
      sku: 10002,
      name: "Product B",
      totalPrice: '',
      values: [{
         price: 13,
         discount: 3,
         color: "purple"
       },
       {
           price: 20,
           discount: 5,
           color: "green"
       }]
   }]
```

I am trying to sum the price and set it to `totalPrice`. So the array will change totalPrice as below:

```
sku: 10001,
      name: "Product A",
      totalPrice: 25,

sku: 10002,
      name: "Product B",
      totalPrice: 33,
```

I believe I need to use something like the below to sum them, however I cannot figure out how to do this!

```
computed: {
    total(){ return this.sites.reduce( (total, item) => item.values. price + total  ,0);}
  },
```

How do I calculate the sum of the price and set it as the totalPrice?

I have traveled SO and find similar threads however nothing that I can get to work with my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
computed: {
  total() {
    let newojv = []
    sites.forEach((item, _) => {
      let s = item.values.map((items2, _) => {
        return items2.price;
      })
      let sum = s.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
      newojv.push({
        sku: item.sku,
        name: item.name,
        totalPrice: sum
      });
    });
    return newojv;
  }
}
```

First for Each of the array of objects below

```
{
  sku: 10001,
  name: "Product A",
  totalPrice: '',
  values: [{
      price: 10,
      discount: 5,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      price: 15,
      discount: 8,
      color: "black"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then for Each of the array of objects below

```
values: [{
      price: 10,
      discount: 5,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      price: 15,
      discount: 8,
      color: "black"
    }
  ]
```

We take a we map the array to get the values of the price, which is 10,15. Then we reduce the array, add it and then push it.

```
let sum = s.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
newojv.push({
    sku: item.sku,
    name: item.name,
    totalPrice: sum
});
```

A working example can be

```js
let sites = [{
  sku: 10001,
  name: "Product A",
  totalPrice: '',
  values: [{
      price: 10,
      discount: 5,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      price: 15,
      discount: 8,
      color: "black"
    }
  ]
}, {
  sku: 10002,
  name: "Product B",
  totalPrice: '',
  values: [{
      price: 13,
      discount: 3,
      color: "purple"
    },
    {
      price: 20,
      discount: 5,
      color: "green"
    }
  ]
}]
let newojv = []
sites.forEach((item, _) => {
  let s = item.values.map((items2, _) => {
    return items2.price;
  })
  let sum = s.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  newojv.push({
    sku: item.sku,
    name: item.name,
    totalPrice: sum
  });
});
console.log(newojv)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'm just trying to figure out how to update my array instead of creating new objects in the array. I'm struggling to figure out how to do this, do you have any pointers? thanks!

Comment: That is not safe. This might generate unexpected results. It's best you use a fresh array instead of the same on you pushed on because we are reading the data from it while pushing to it.

Comment: Ah ok! So I delete the old array and replace it?

Comment: Why delete the first array? Just push the total to a new array and return that.

Comment: If I do that won't I end up with with the old array with totalPrice as ' ' and a whole new array as with totalPrice set? If that makes sense!

Comment: Well, no idea what you are talking about there. But you have to return something from the function not to modify an array. This is the best solution with vue.js

Comment: The question is, why do you want to store the `totalPrice` in the data itself? Like what @weegee proposed, you shouldn't really be mutating your data. The sum of the prices should be a computed property that is abstracted away from the data itself.

Comment: Ah ok, think I understand. I'll see if I can work this into my code!